# ExpressJS, NodeJs and Redis Simple Login Error

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm having a problem about checking the username and password in Redis it says username and password is undefined. I hope you can help me to fix this problem in NodeJs/ExpressJs guys.

**CODE:**

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();
var user, pass;

app.use(express.bodyParser());

client.on("error", function (err) {
console.log("error event - " + client.host + ":" + client.port + " - " + err);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log("");
console.log("--------------------");
console.log(req.body.user.username);
console.log(req.body.user.password);

console.log("--------EOF---------");
client.hmget(req.body.user.username + user, req.body.user.pasword + pass,
 redis.print);
if (req.body.user.username && req.body.user.password == user && pass)
{
    res.write("Successfully logged in!");
}
else
{
    res.write("Username or Password is incorrect");
}
console.log("req.body.username: " + req.body.username);
console.log("req.body.password: " + req.body.password);
console.log("username: " + user);
console.log("username: " + pass);
res.end();

});

app.listen(80)
```

Here's my index.html code.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/">

Username: <input type="text" name="user[username]" > <br>
Password: <input type="text" name="user[password]"> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: Redis client is asynchronous. You need a callback somewhere to fill user and pass.

Comment: Can you help me fix my code? Cause I don't get it :( Thanks Didier Spezia :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Redis instance contains a hash object called "credentials" containing the association between users and passwords.

```
HMSET credentials didier mypass
```

I would rewrite the post method as follows:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("--------------------");
    console.log(req.body.user.username);
    console.log(req.body.user.password);
    console.log("--------EOF---------");
    client.hmget( 'credentials', req.body.user.username, function (err,pass) {
        console.log("req.body.username: " + req.body.user.username);
        console.log("req.body.password: " + req.body.user.password);
        console.log("pass: " + pass );
        console.log("err: " + err );
        if ( (!err) && pass && pass == req.body.user.password )
            res.write( "Successfully logged in!" );
        else
            res.write( "Username or Password is incorrect");
        res.end();
     });
 });
```

With this code, I have the successful login message, and the following trace:

```
--------------------
didier
mypass
--------EOF---------
req.body.username: didier
req.body.password: mypass
pass: mypass
err: null
```

Please note this way of storing credentials and this authentication mechanism are totally not secure.